# Java networking input stream for client

Tags: java, networking, client

I'm very new to networking in java and wanted to create a network chat program, I have found a few tutorials online and kind of drifted from that. I have the server of my program working and the only thing that is interfering is when I try to read the chat messages that the server sends over. The server does send the bytes of data over since the print message does work. So the problem is that the while loop never ends, what can this be a problem of?

```
public String[] updateChatDialog() throws IOException{
    String returnString = "";
    int accessed = -1;

    while((accessed = in.read()) > 0){
        System.out.println((char)accessed);
        returnString = returnString + (char)accessed;
    }
    System.out.println(returnString);
    return stringToTable(returnString);
}
```

Any tips on java networking would be helpful!

I do reset the BufferedInputStream every time the chats are rendered into a string, AKA the method above with the return in it.

Answer (score 0):

The 'problem' is that your loop reads until end of stream, and the peer isn't closing the connection so EOS never arrives.

If you want to read *messages* you have to define them yourself. The easiest thing for you to do in this application is write and read lines, with e.g. `PrintWriter.println()` and `BufferedReader.readLine().`